Error with grouping and displaying data in the header according to 2 parameters
       <converter:DateTimeToStatusConverter x:Key="DateTimeToStatusConverter"/>
       <converter:DateTimeStartToStatisConverter x:Key="DateTimeStartToStatisConverter"/>
       <converter:PriorityColorConverter x:Key="PriorityColorConverter"/>
       <converter:Base64ToBitmapImageConverter x:Key="Base64ToBitmapImageConverter"/>
       <converter:StringEmptyConverter x:Key="StringEmptyConverter"/>
       <converter:TypeAnswerConverter x:Key="TypeAnswerConverter"/>
       <converter:DueDateConverter x:Key="DueDateConverter"/>
       <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding QuestionInspectionsFinded}" x:Key="InspectionsGroup">
           <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
               <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="idInspection"/>
               <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="idQuiz"/>
           </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
       </CollectionViewSource>

<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource MyScroll}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,10,0,0">
            <ListView  Name="tasksList" Style="{x:Null}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource InspectionsGroup}}" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Margin="10,0,0,0">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding EditOrAddInspectionCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=tasksList}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <ListView.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <ItemsPresenter/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </ListView.Template>
                <ListView.GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,5"/>
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                            <Border Background="#a6b1ff" CornerRadius="10" BorderBrush="#222d3d" BorderThickness="0,0,0,5">
                                                <Expander IsExpanded="False" Padding="10 -5 10 10" Foreground="Black" >
                                                    <Expander.Header>
                                                        <Grid>
                                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Arial" Foreground="#222d3d" Text="{Binding Path=Items[0].InspactionFullName}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-10,0, 0, 0" Width="auto"/>
                                                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="13" FontFamily="Arial" Foreground="#222d3d" Text="{Binding Path=Items[0].StartInsp, Converter={StaticResource DateTimeStartToStatisConverter}}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="auto"/>
                                                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="13" FontFamily="Arial" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="auto">
                                                                <TextBlock.Style>
                                                                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#222d3d"/>
                                                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Items[0].EndInsp}" Value="{x:Null}">
                                                                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF53ED00"/>
                                                                                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                                                                            </DataTrigger>
                                                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                                                    </Style>
                                                                </TextBlock.Style>
                                                                <TextBlock.Text>
                                                                    <Binding Path="Items[0].EndInsp" Converter="{StaticResource DateTimeToStatusConverter}"/>
                                                                </TextBlock.Text>
                                                            </TextBlock>
                                                        </Grid>
                                                    </Expander.Header>
                                                    <Expander.Content>
                                                        <ItemsPresenter/>
                                                    </Expander.Content>
                                                </Expander>
                                            </Border>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    </GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,5"/>
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                            <Border Background="#a6b1ff" CornerRadius="10" BorderBrush="#222d3d" BorderThickness="0,0,0,5">
                                                <Expander IsExpanded="False" Padding="10 -5 10 10" Foreground="Black" >
                                                    <Expander.Header>
                                                        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Arial" Foreground="#222d3d" Text="{Binding Path=Items[0].QuizName}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-10,0, 0, 0" Width="auto"/>
                                                    </Expander.Header>
                                                    <Expander.Content>
                                                        <ItemsPresenter/>
                                                    </Expander.Content>
                                                </Expander>
                                            </Border>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    </GroupStyle>
                </ListView.GroupStyle>
            </ListView>
        </ScrollViewer>
    public class Questions
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int? idQuiz { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int? idTypeAnswer { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string QuizName { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string MarkFullName { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string QuizNameMarker { get => QuizName + " - " + MarkFullName; }
    [NotMapped]
    public int? idMarkers { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public ObservableCollection<string> ImagePathsCollection { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public ObservableCollection<InspectionAnswer> Answers {  get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public int idInspection { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string InspactionFullName { get => "Обход № " + idInspection; }
    [NotMapped]
    public DateTime? StartInsp { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public DateTime? EndInsp { get; set; }
}

I have a problem with outputting data for the first grouping.
I'm grouping the QuestionInspectionsFinded collection by idInspection
then by idQuiz
for the first grouping you need to display InspactionFullName, StartInsp, EndInsp, but the program does not see them and simply displays emptiness. I checked the converters are working correctly, the data necessary for output is added for each value in the collection (InspactionFullName, StartInsp, EndInsp)
Also, grouping by idQuiz correctly displays QuizName
where could the error be?
